# Problems with getting an image to show in a paged list

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I have the following code, and it displays the listed text and the pagination at the bottom all fine. But when I try to get the images from the child page into the list it errors for me. Any ideas why?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<div role="main" id="main">


    <div id="blogPageFeatures">
        <!-- loop through all of the child pages (blog posts) and grab data to output as a summary -->
        @{
        var pageSize =3;
        var page =1;int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["page"],out page);
        var items =Model.Content.Children().Where(x => x.IsDocumentType("BlogArticle")).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate);
        var totalPages =(int)Math.Ceiling((double)items.Count()/(double)pageSize);

        if(page > totalPages)
        {
                page = totalPages;
        }
        else if(page <1)
        {
                page =1;
        }
        }




        @foreach(var item in items.Skip((page -1)* pageSize).Take(pageSize))
        {


                        <a href="@item.Url">

                                <!-- The next image line is where it errors -->
                                <img src="@Umbraco.Media(item.Children.blogArticleImage).Url">

                                    <h2>@item.Name</h2>
                                    <p class="blogTileDate">@item.CreateDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")</p>





                            </a>

        }


<div class="clearfix"></div>


        <!-- Pagination START -->
        @if(totalPages >1)
        {
        <div class="pagination">
                        <ul>
                                @if(page >1)
                                {
                                        <li><a href="?page=@(page-1)">Prev</a></li>
                                }
                                @for(int p =1; p < totalPages +1; p++)
                                {
                                        var active =(p == page)?" class=\"active\"":string.Empty;
                                        <li@(Html.Raw(active))>
                                                <a href="?page=@p">@p</a>
                                        </li>
                                }
                                @if(page <totalPages)
                                {
                                        <li><a href="?page=@(page+1)">Next</a></li>
                                }
                        </ul>
                </div>
                            }
        <!-- Pagination END -->





        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: It's this my friend:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>' does not contain a definition for 'blogArticleImage' and no extension method 'blogArticleImage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting Model.Content.Children, which is a strongly typed collection of IPublishedContent objects. You are then calling item.Children.blogArticlImage, which is not going to work, as you're trying to get the a property on the children of the item, not a property of the item itself. You're also trying to use dynamic syntax, which won't work on the strongly typed objects. Try changing your image code to:

```
<img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetPropertyValue<int>("blogArticleImage")).Url">
```

That should do te trick, one thing to note is that if an item doesn't have an image set, or the image that has been selected has been deleted, it'll throw an error. A more robust approach would be something like this:

```
var imageSrc = "ADD DEFAULT IMAGE PATH HERE";
var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(item.GetPropertyValue<int>("blogArticleImage"));
if (media != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(media.Url))
{
    imageSrc = media.Url;
}
<mig src="@imageSrc">
```